# How to change color of backGround on app load(onCreate())?

Tags: android

I am trying to change r=the color of the back ground on app load. For this I have used something like this :

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final View view= new View(getApplicationContext());
        view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
        });
        addListenerOnButton();
    }
```

This does not work. See the emulator screen shot below :
[image]

As you can see the back ground color is still white . Any ideas on what i can do to rectify this ?

Comment: I don't see where you set the new contentView with your view here.

Comment: That's the problem, i dont have any explicit views except a text view . Can i use that here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple. Try this way.

```
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

For ex:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
}
```

Here `findViewById(android.R.id.content)` will return `ContentView` of current activity. Then you can set background for this view.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: This is excellent, worked like a charm. Cam you perhaps explain the code a little, especially `this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)` . Anyways already up voted and accepted after stack's 5 min limit .

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `view.post()` is not necessary, because `onCreate()` already runs in the UI thread. Secondly, you are creating a View and setting the background of it, but you never set the view to anywhere, it's just an Object that never gets drawn. There are 2 solutions:

either:

```
View view= new View(this);
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
setContentView(view);
```

or, probably better:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
View view = findViewById(R.id.root_laout); // set the root_layout in the layout xml file
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: That creates a problem for me , as i normally set my content view as `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`, which is then used by my `addListenerOnButton()` method . So if i again set the content view to view, the app  stops working .

Comment: set the background to the root view in the xml file if you have linearlayout or relative layout add this attribute to the same android:backgroud="#000000"

Comment: See the second solution that i have posted in the answer. just set the id of the root layout in your layout xml file to root_layout.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```