# Trying to change main activity background color on button click

Tags: android, android-layout

Here's my main:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeBackground(v);
        }
    }); 
}
```

I've tried the follow methods, both of which have failed:

```
public void changeBackground(View v) 
{
      View someView = findViewById(R.id.main);
      View root = someView.getRootView();
      root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
}

public void changeBackground(View v) 
{
      View root = v.getRootView();
      root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
}
```

I searched and found the solution for how to solve this in [How to set background color of Activity to white programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761686/how-to-set-background-color-of-activity-to-white-programmatically); the solution posted was:

```
  // Now get a handle to any View contained 
  // within the main layout you are using
  View someView = findViewById(R.id.randomViewInMainLayout);

  // Find the root view
  View root = someView.getRootView()

  // Set the color
  root.setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.red);
```

When I try `android.R.color.red`, eclipse tells me that it should be in the form in my examples.

I did manage to change the background of my button with:

```
public void changeBackground(View v) 
{
    v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
}
```

So, I'm pretty confident that the issue is not with: `getResources().getColor(R.color.red)`.  I've tried many different ways, and I'm not getting anywhere.  For reference, here's my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="@color/LightCyan"
    android:id="@+id/main">

   <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:text="@string/welcome"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

   <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2" > 

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/resume_button"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/resume" 
           android:background="@color/Plum"/>

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/newgame_button"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="@string/new_game"
           android:background="@color/Plum" 
           android:onClick="changeBackground"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16697291/how-to-change-color-of-background-on-app-loadoncreate/16697561#16697561) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeBackground(v);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Change this to

```
   Activity activity;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    actvity = this;
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.newgame_button);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

           actvity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: It grabs the current `View` from `android.R.id.content` because you said `activity = this`?  So, `android.R.id.content` is a special variable?

Comment: @SteveP. Not like that. Used to get the activity's content. refer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273436/how-to-get-activitys-content-view). Here `this` refers to current activity only.

Answer (score 0):

In my application I use the following code to change the background:

```
View view = this.getWindow().getDecorView();
view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Try it, maybe it will work for you.

Comment: If this is not working then probably you have something overlaying your Activity background. The code that I posted changes the background of the root, which means that if you have any Layout in your activity this change will not be visible because of view hierarchy.

Comment: I posted all of my code above.  There isn't anything relevant missing.

Comment: Then I am really curious why my code is not working for you... Strange

Comment: I'm relatively new to android, so I have no idea.  What I did in my answer ended up working, though.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

```
public void changeBackground(View v) 
{
      View root = findViewById(R.id.main);
      root.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
}
```

Apparently, using `getRootView()` is not good when you're dealing with your main `View`.  I don't know, but this worked.

Answer (score 0):

@Steve P.

Change this

```
  public void changeBackground(View v)  {
    v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red)); }
```

with this one

```
 public void ChangeBackground(View v)
{
    View parentsView = (View) v.getParent();
    parentsView.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
}
```